# Desktop/Webapp shared database overwriting data on duplicate key

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

I'm developing a webapp that shares a database with an in-production desktop app (aka I cannot modify the database, only try to mimic behaviors). The module I'm working on now will store notes into this database in the `notes` table. I was able to get it to work, I added notes and they showed up in the desktop app, then after some time I realized the notes actual note text and descriptions were being overwritten. Looking at the rows in the database, I noticed `modified_by` user was set, telling me there was a duplicate key on insert, then later update. The primary key for this table is to auto-increment so I was very confused. After some digging I found a table called `counters` with a column called `notes` that had a count that matched the current index of `notes` table. Before just simply +1 the counter on every insert, I downloaded wireshark onto the db server and recorded the traffic on the db port and found this:

(Procedure when adding a note from desktop app)

```
UPDATE counters SET in_use = 'Y';
SELECT notes FROM counters WHERE key_col = 1;
/* Desktop app uses current count for new index */
UPDATE counters SET notes = /* current count +1 */ WHERE key_col = 1;
UPDATE counters SET in_use = 'N';
/* ...Inserts new note here with explicit ID = current count ... */
```

Now I'm even more confused. Why set the table to auto-increment at all? Second, there was never any checking of `in_use` before selecting the count and adding one... so what's the point of `in_use`? Couldn't this code lead to overwrites if two users inserted at the same time? Wouldn't the correct way to do this be to lock the `counters` table for every operation? I could try this, but I'm not sure how the desktop app will handle encountering a lock (based on experience - fatal error).

Aside from exactly duplicating this procedure and hoping for the best, I'm not exactly sure where to go from here. One thought is to:

```
<?php
const MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
$curKey;

for($i = 0; $i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; $i++){
    /*
    SELECT in_use, notes from counters where key_col = 1;
    ...
    */
    if( 'N' === $result['in_use'] ){
        $curKey = $result['notes'];
        /* INSERT count here - $curKey++ */
        break;
    }
    /* Sleep for .25 seconds to allow for current operation to finish */
    usleep(250000);
}

if( null == $curKey ){
    throw \Exception('Could not insert note because counter table locked after '. MAX_ATTEMPTS .' attempts');
}

/* INSET note code here... */
```

This seems ok, but could still possibly overwrite because a) time between select count and insert new count b) Desktop app does not seem to do any checking.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

**EDIT**: Made a stored procedure to do checking during select and insert.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`testUser`@`%` FUNCTION `getNextNoteIndex`(appKey INTEGER) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    SELECT IF(`in_use` = 'N', `notes`, NULL) INTO @curIndex FROM `counters` WHERE `app_key` = appKey;
    IF @curIndex IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        SET @newIndex = @curIndex + 1;
        UPDATE `counters` SET `notes` = @newIndex WHERE `app_key` = appKey AND `in_use` = 'N' AND `notes` = @curIndex;
        IF ROW_COUNT() = 1
        THEN
            RETURN @newIndex;
        END IF;
    END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT testDB.getNextNoteIndex(1) AS $index;
```

Comment: Another thought, I could pause for half a second after getting counter value, then try insert and see if I get duplicate key, but this will slow down my inserts.

Comment: This sounds to me like it is happening due to bad practice of using the same db for different applications. If you have the proper access to db you need to give the tables and columns for your app more unique names.

Comment: @EternalHour You may be right, but I require my webapp notes to show up in the desktop app, otherwise this entire project is useless.

Comment: That would not be an issue, the desktop app would just need to select the notes using the new names.

Comment: @EternalHour I did not develop the desktop app and have 0 control of what it does or does not do. If I did, I would just correct this logic and be done hehe

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for what purpose they would need to create a table that does the auto incrementing, it doesn't sound like a standard solution.

I'm confused as to what you can and cannot change (db, backend code, etc):

If you're on the inside, are you not able to ask the developer who built that intermediate incrementing table what it is for and potentially get clarity there, or bypass it altogether.

If you're on the outside, does it make sense to ask them for an API and use the endpoints they gave you? Then any problems that arise from overwriting fall on their court.

Comment: There exists no API, further, no contact with the DEVS. Also, an API would not help here as there seems to be a bug in their original logic.